# How to adjust alignment of 3 columns in PHP with the help of CSS?

Tags: html, css

I need to display 3 columns in the same alignment: col1 col2 and col3 into my dynamic website. Col3 doesn't appear on the same line of col1 and col2. It appears just beneath it. It should be displayed on the same alignment of col1 and col2. I can adjust it by applying margin-top option but it isn't the right solution. Since contents of these columns are extracted from database, height isn't defined. The contents of col1 and col2 pushes col3. So, I couldn't manage its alignment. How can this be solved?

```css
#content {
  width: 900px;
  margin: auto;
}
#col {
  width: 600px;
  float: left;
}
#col1 {
  width: 300px;
  float: left;
}
#col2 {
  width: 300px;
  float: right;
}
#col3 {
  width: 300px;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <div id="col">
    <div id="col1">Text of col1...</div>
    <div id="col2">Text of col2...</div>
  </div>
  <div id="col3">Text of col3...</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works fine http://jsfiddle.net/3d4mwkd3/

Comment: Why don't you put the 3rd one in the div with id=col ?

Comment: Agree with Danko... It works for me too...

Comment: @jklyn which browser are you using?

Comment: @cuSK I'm using firefox.

Comment: I'm also using firefox, your code works fine. As [Danko](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2887133/)'s link, [jsfiddle.net/3d4mwkd3/](http://jsfiddle.net/3d4mwkd3/).

Comment: @Danko -@tramp Yes, it works on above link I've also tested. But in my site, col3 is displayed at right side just beneath the col2.

Comment: Then we aren't able to help u my friend maybe give us the link to your site ... Check if the main container is wide enough to enclose the three columns

Comment: @Danko I've not uploaded the site yet.

Comment: use this `#content{width:850px;float:left}`